# How to use TVirtualStringTree AccessibleName or implement accessibility?

Tags: delphi, accessibility, c++builder, virtualtreeview

I can see that `TVirtualStringTree` has a property called `AccessibleName` yet, I don't see it working, that is, giving the string which is set to screen reader such as NVDA.

What I tried is setting this in the `OnGetText` event but that doesn't seem to produce any results (e.g. `Sender->AccessibleName = "my node name";`). All it reads is entire contents of the tree, not just a current node just the same as if I didn't make any change to the property, and if node is changed (using keyboard) it doesn't do anything.

What it should be reading is - Column name - column content - another column name - another column content etc. like it does with the regular `TListView`.

There seems to be an implementation of iAccessible interface here - https://github.com/Virtual-TreeView/Virtual-TreeView/blob/master/Source/VTAccessibility.pas

Can you share some example how to use VirtualTreeView built in accessibility to make the component readable to screen readers as it seems that such examples are really scarce?

**Edit (for future googlers):**

Related question which solves the C++ Builder accessiblity unit linking:

[Implementing VirtualTreeView TVTDefaultAccessibleProvider in C++ Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114996/implementing-virtualtreeview-tvtdefaultaccessibleprovider-in-c-builder)

**Edit 2 (for future googlers):**

Additionally, `TVirtualStringTree` also provides `OnGetImageText`. This event is used to provide accessible text for images used in the tree, for example if you have multiple images in a node to represent certain states you can describe these states with image labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `VirtualTrees.Accessibility` unit to the `uses` section (project or one of your units). This unit registers accessibility providers, it will read only the focused item in the tree along with column names.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - Yes, you're correct, it does work for Delphi. But including the `VirtualTrees.Accessibility.hpp` in C++ Builder does not help as it doesn't execute the part which registers accessibility providers (the part is absent from the hpp file but listed in the pas file). I think I'll have to ask a new question how to register those since it affects only C++ Builder, not Delphi.